# how to add advanced custom field variable in another shortcode

Tags: wordpress, acfpro

I have problem in custom post type: I want to echo one shortcode that variable input in acf plugin

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode("[sdfile url=the_field('downloadlink')']")
?>
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

i fix it

```
<?php $variable2 = get_field('downloadlink');
echo do_shortcode("[sdfile url='$variable2']"); 
?>
```

Comment: consider to describe what did you do in order to fix the problem instead of `i fixed it`